# Parametrization of a cylinder that is parallel to x axis

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, surfaces, parametric

The answer is no it does not matter.

The surface is $y^2+z^2=4$, I parametrized it so:

$\mathbf r=x \mathbf i +2\cos\theta \mathbf j + 2\sin\theta \mathbf k$

But Pauls Outline works through the problem with the **j** and **k** components switched. Does it matter which way I go about parametrizing this surface?

Comment: both are allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It really doesn't matter. Thinking of a similar problem in two dimensions, both
$$\cos\theta\,\mathbf{i} + \sin\theta\,\mathbf{j}\text{ and }
  \sin\theta\,\mathbf{i} + \cos\theta\,\mathbf{j}$$
parametrize the unit circle, but in different ways.